# SQL query to order by the top averages of previous data

Tags: mysql, subquery

Given a table with data with these columns (other columns too, but, these are the important ones):

```
gameid awayscore homescore
1      3         8
2      4         2
3      4         9
4      15        5
5      0         8
6      4         10
...
```

What I am looking for is to get the average margin of victory over the previous 3 games (assuming gameid is the order they were played), so, on game 6, it should be (6+8+10=24, average 8),  on game 5 (8+10+5=23, average 7.666), etc.   And then show the weeks where the 3-game average was the highest.

I tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT g.gameid,
(SELECT AVG(scores.ave) FROM (SELECT ABS(awayscore-homescore) ave FROM games gs
WHERE (gs.gameid<=g.gameid)
ORDER BY gameid DESC LIMIT 3) scores) margin
FROM `games` g
GROUP BY g.gameid
ORDER BY margin DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

But I get "Unknown column 'g.gameid' in 'where clause'", I assume because it is a subquery of a subquery(?), and it loses the reference?  I am at a loss of how to structure it otherwise though to work correctly (if it is possible at all).

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT g.gameid,
   (SELECT AVG(ABS(awayscore-homescore))
      FROM games gs
       WHERE (gs.gameid<=g.gameid)
             AND (gs.gameid>g.gameid-3)
    ) margin
FROM `games` g
ORDER BY margin DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5dc4c7/11)

**UPDATE** if you want to use gamedate (datetime) to order your game, you can create a game order (gorder) number based on this sort for everytime you select from games like the below query.

```
SELECT g.gameid,
   (SELECT AVG(ABS(awayscore-homescore))
      FROM 
       (SELECT awayscore,homescore,@rank:=@rank+1 as gorder
        FROM games,(SELECT @rank:=0)r
        ORDER BY gamedate ASC
        )gs
       WHERE (gs.gorder <= g.gorder)
             AND (gs.gorder > g.gorder-3)
    ) margin
FROM (SELECT games.gameid,@rank2:=@rank2+1 as gorder
        FROM games,(SELECT @rank2:=0)r2
        ORDER BY gamedate ASC) g
ORDER BY margin DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e9/1)

Comment: Thanks... that is true... I was maybe trying to "simplify" the query a bit too much for the purposes of this post for my own good though.... in my actual query, the game_id's do NOT really "line up"... I have to sort by gamedate, so, it is really "ORDER BY gamedate DESC LIMIT 3"... so, I can't just depend on a given X-# scenario.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include another query at bottom that instead of querying games, it adds a @rank variable as gorder (game order)...so that it ranks games based on gamedate...check it out and let me know if it works for ya

Comment: Thanks... didn't think about using a counter in the query, need to think about that more often.   I had to do a little modification, but, that worked.